# How to show multiple pages in PrintPreview control in c#

Tags: c#

In my Windows application, I print multiple items in my PrintPriview control but when the items are more than 25, it doesn't go the next page to print the rest of the items. I know that we need to use e.Hasmorepages = true but I can't figure out how to use it correctly. Please help.

Screen shot -
[Click here to see screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b0P8.png)

```
  private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = Properties.Resources.logo2;
        Image image = bmp;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(25, 160));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Client Name: " + ClientNameTextBox.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(25, 190));

        e.Graphics.DrawString("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(25, 235));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Item Name", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(30, 255));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Quantity", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(380, 255));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Unit Price (£)", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(510, 255));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Total Price (£)", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(660, 255));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(25, 270));

        int yPos = 295;

        foreach (var i in shoppingCart)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(i.ItemName, new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(30, yPos));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(i.Quantity.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(400, yPos));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(i.UnitPrice.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(550, yPos));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(i.TotalPrice.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(700, yPos));
            yPos += 30;

        }

        e.Graphics.DrawString("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(25, yPos));

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Total Amount:      £" + TotalAmountTextBox.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(550, yPos + 30));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Sales Tax (16%): £" + SalesTaxTextBox.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(550, yPos + 60));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Total To Pay:       £" + TotalToPayTextBox.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(550, yPos + 90));

        e.Graphics.DrawString("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(25, yPos + 120));

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to

a) watch the `y` value

b) set `HasMorePages` to true when it is over a maximum page height value

c) **leave the printpage event**.

It'll be called again if needed, ie when you either print or preview the next page..

You also need to keep track of the **cart items** you have printed in a **class level variable**; replace the `foreach` by a `for` loop storing/using that item number! Break out of the loop and later also `return` from the event when `y` is larger than the maximum that will fit on your page!

Also design for repeating the headers, but you got that right I think! Finally another class level variable should keep track of the **page numbers**!

Comment: Thanks, TaW. I have changed foreach to for loop. Instead of looking for height, I used the number of item displayed.